# Can't install anything with pip - missing coloredlogs/METADATA

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm currently building a chatbot for my exam at school and apparently `pip` decided to stop working. When I try to install a package/dependency I get the following errormessage:

```
No metadata found in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/fredarch/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coloredlogs-10.0.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Same thing happens when I use the command `pip show coloredlogs`

Comment: Is your question solved by now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably re-install coloredlogs with conda:

```
conda install coloredlogs
```

after this you should be able to use pip to install packages once again.